# Joomla Bug - Possible Security - I can't be sure

Tags: security, joomla, captcha, joomla3.0

I am fairly well versed with Joomla, and I am running 3.0.3 on ten different sites I manage for clients. I log in to these sites very often to check all is ok. Today for the first time, when I went to the log in page I experienced a page saying "ARE YOU HUMAN" with a Captacha on. I have looked at the source code and I can say no indication of Joomla, and all CSS is contained within the file. Once you enter the captcha it takes you to the index page. Then weirdly I have also viewed another site (different server all togeather) and seen the same thing. There are no obvious hack attempts (such as content changed) but seams odd this has happened twice in one day for the first time and looks very unlike Joomla?

Screenshot:
[image]

Has anyone else experienced this? I have searched about it but can't find anything about it on Google etc

Comment: SOunds like  phishing to me to be, i would not enter any password into a "captcha" form that is unexpected.

I would quickly change any site passwords and then check your extensions to see if they have any known vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go ask your hoster, he probably set this up himself.

Comment: As I say in the question - it is over two totally seperate hosts (GoDaddy and Heart). Whats more I set them up manually (didn't use they're one click installs etc)

Comment: I would have suspected it may be a security page set up by the hoster to protect the admin section. But I may be wrong. Of course it's not coming from Joomla itself. So it's either a hacked site or something the hoster(s) did.